# My code is not working for large inputs

Tags: c

The problem statement is here https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4fe12e4cbb829

```
You are distributing candy among children. All the children sit in a line and each of
them  has a rating score according to his or her usual performance. Each child gets 
at least 1 piece. Children get jealous of their immediate neighbors, so if two 
children sit next to each other then the one with the higher rating must get 
more candies. You wants to save money, so minimize the total number of candies.

Input: A file with the children's ratings, 1 per line.
```

And my code is working for small input sizes but for a very large input its either not giving any output ( on the interview.com console) or deviating from the answer by a small amount on my system.
What cold be the error in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i, j, n, rating[100000], candy[1000000], total = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i=0 ; i < n; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&rating[i]);
        candy[i] = 1;
    }

    for (i=0 ; i < n+1 ; i++)
    {
      for (j=1 ; j < n-1; j++)
      {
          if( rating[j-1] < rating[j] )
          {
              if ( candy[j-1] >= candy[j] )
                  candy[j]++;
          }

          if( rating[j+1] < rating[j] )
          {
              if ( candy[j+1] >= candy[j] )
                  candy[j]++;
          }       
      }  
    }

    for (i=0 ; i < n ; i++)
        total = total + candy[i];

    printf("%d",total);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How large is that value causing error?

Comment: that means you code needs a longer time for large input data, try improve your algorithm

Comment: What problem is your code is trying to solve?

Comment: I dont know about the upper bound but I took around n=16000 as the input.
Its taking actually O(N^2) time but its working on my system though only deviating from the answer by a small amount.
@junjanes The problem is mentioned in the link in the question.

Comment: Note that you're trying to use at least 8 MB of stack which may result in stack overflow, depending on your platform.

Comment: @PaulR For example its giving 33554 instead of 33556 on my system (Its still giving right answers for smaller inputs). So I guess it is not a case of stack overflow here. But on the site on which this question was hosted, its not giving any output.

Comment: @Shivendra: you may still have a stack overflow problem - just because the code *appears* to work for some inputs this doesn't rule it out. However I also see at least one logic bug in your code - I suggest you learn to use a debugger at this point.

Comment: @PaulR: Thanks. I would definitely learn to use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running into one of the translation limits of your implementation with the automatic arrays `rating` and `candy`. Try placing them at file scope, i.e. outside of `main`. Then they have static storage duration. Most systems allow much larger static objects than automatic objects.

Comment: Thanks Jens, this solved the bigger problem of not giving out the result. I am just left with a small logical bug now which I am sure I  will debug.